# Extra Flat Fee at Checkout with BigCommerce -- Does the API Support Ability to Implement This

Tags: bigcommerce

We are currently evaluating several e-commerce platforms, BigCommerce being one of them.

The product that we are considering selling requires the addition of a required additional "setup fee" with some SKUs (for example, art work prep for an extra $20.00, independent of unit cost of the product or options selected).

My initial though on how to implement this is through the addition of a 2nd SKU that is automatically added when a SKU is added to the cart that has a particular attribute (e.g., attribute type: Setup Fee; attribute value: $20.00).  This attribute would tell custom code to create the setup fee SKU and add it to the cart as well.

Of course code would also need to be developed to maintain the integrity of the cart and the setup fee.  If the original product is deleted, the setup fee should be deleted.  The setup fee should also not be allowed to be deleted or changed if the product that put it in the cart is still in the cart.

My question is -- Is the BigCommerce API rich enough (methods, eventing, etc...) to handle this custom coding scenario?

I spoke a brief bit with BigCommerce support and they indicated that it may be able to be done with JavaScript but that's the furthest we took it as the tech sounded unsure.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this via setting up product rules. The API lets you do that. 
https://devdocs.bigcommerce.com/

You can setup product rules in such a way that it adds that extra $20 for the specific product. 
https://devdocs.bigcommerce.com/display/API/Rules

BC does not support webhooks yet. But it is something in pipeline. For this, I am assuming if you are using rules, you won't need webhooks. Instead of adding another product in the cart with a different SKU automatically, you would just apply the rule so that the setup automatically gets added.

Make sense?

Comment: I've tried to use product rules via the control panel in the admin section.  I don't believe it's possible to add an extra flat fee that is independent of quantity ordered (e.g, extra $20 regardless if 1 of 100 is ordered).  Are you saying that this could be done, but only via the API and not the control panel?